# Invoking R CMD SHLIB through system() doesn't find GSL library

Tags: r, c, linker, shared-libraries

I have a C program that uses GNU Scientific Library (GSL) for root finding and I want to make this into a shared library (.so or .dll) for use in R.

Say my GSL_MRE.c file looks like this:

```
#include <gsl/gsl_math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_roots.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_errno.h>
#include <R.h>

int gsl_rootsolve ()
{
  const gsl_root_fdfsolver_type *T;
  gsl_root_fdfsolver *s;
  T = gsl_root_fdfsolver_newton;
  s = gsl_root_fdfsolver_alloc (T);
  
  printf ("using %s method\n", gsl_root_fdfsolver_name (s));
  
  gsl_root_fdfsolver_free (s);
  
  return 0;
}
```

If I run the following in Terminal on MacOS 10.13.6:

```
$ R CMD SHLIB GSL_MRE.c -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -L/opt/local/lib
```

($ is the terminal prompt) it creates GSL_MRE.so that I can load by executing in R:

```
R> dyn.load(paste("GSL_MRE", .Platform$dynlib.ext, sep = ""))
```

(R> is R prompt)

But when I try to create the .so file from R with system():

```
R> system("R CMD SHLIB GSL_MRE.c -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -L/opt/local/lib")
```

It can't find the header files. I get:

```
GSL_MRE.c:1:10: fatal error: 'gsl/gsl_math.h' file not found
#include <gsl/gsl_math.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [GSL_MRE.o] Error 1
```

I've been trying to set all sorts of FLAGS in `~/.R/Makevars`, but nothing works. My Makevars currently only contains the following line:

```
CC=gcc -Wall -Wextra
```

Why does system() from R not work? And how do I make the .so from R programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few packages that wrap around the GSL, I recommend you study them. At a minimum you could use `gsl-config` (which you should test for) to derive include and linker statements. On my Uvuntu system:

```
edd@rob:~$ gsl-config --cflags
-I/usr/include
edd@rob:~$ gsl-config --libs
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
edd@rob:~$
```

More fundamentally, you got trapped between *linking* (where you correctly pointo to the GSL libraries) and *compiling* (where you have told the compiler where your GSL headers reside).  You apprently need to tell it on your system.

Also, some packages provide facilities. My `RcppGSL` package offers some simple vector and matrix wrappers, but also deals with GSL detection so that for example my `RcppZiggurat` (which uses GSL RNGs) can use:

```
edd@rob:~$ cat git/rcppziggurat/src/Makevars
PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I. -I../inst/include
## Use the R_HOME indirection to support installations of multiple R version
PKG_LIBS = `$(R_HOME)/bin/Rscript -e "RcppGSL:::LdFlags()"`
edd@rob:~$
```

It's not a trivial problem as you need to sort our compiling and linking, but it has been done before so you can lean on that.